# Why does the tapered part of a Wing have such high coefficient of Lift?

Tags: aerodynamics

If we take a Trapezoid wing shape as an example and see that it has low $c_l$ near the root of the wing and very high $c_l$ at the tip. The Lift generated, however, is reversed to the that of the $c_l$.

Comment: The aviation SE site is a better option for aerodynamics questions.

Comment: i think you mean Cl not Ca?

Comment: Indeed! I have corrected it.

Comment: Isn't this backwards?  Lift comes from creating a greater wind speed above the wing than below, which would imply shape and area.